# How do I replace a vector of words with different cases, with the lower case characters only?

Tags: r

I have a vector of sample names:
`names <- c("ABCdef", "ABCdef", "ABCdef")`
How do I use regular expressions and gsub to return:
`"def", "def", "def"`?
I.E., how do I write a gsub command that replaces the full names with only the lower-case letters in the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to remove all upper case letters in a string:

```
names <- c("ABCdef", "ABCdef", "ABCdef")

gsub("[[:upper:]]*", "", names)
[1] "def" "def" "def"
```